# Unnecessary indenting in bash

Tags: bash, vi, putty, indent

I have been trying to paste text from one file to another in bash. I'm working in Putty.

To be more clear,
I have a file `hotel.txt` with some lines of text that are indented, thus have tabs and spaces.
When I paste a few of those indented lines into another file created using `vi`,
they are pasted with a tab extra each.

All my text is automatically indented with each line having an extra tab as soon as I paste using the right click mouse button.

Does anyone have any solution?

I've tried `:set paste`, but doesn't work with me apparently.

Comment: general coding advice: It is good practice to replace tabs by spaces. Most editors have such configuration option

Comment: Do you mean while indenting my script, I must use spaces? 
Thanks alot!

Comment: @hek2mgl I've heard the other way around. So do most of the people [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/72/100154)

Comment: Yes, in the moment you are coding. My editor for example (vim) inserts 4 spaces when I press tab. I have `set expandtab` and `set ts=4` in my `vimrc`. This makes things easier, believe me.. :)

Comment: It's odd that `:se paste` doesn't work.

Comment: @Antarus People might think what they want. I can only say the software world beside the guys who had upvoted the answer that you linked, agreed about that spaces should be used in favour of tabs.

Comment: I've read about :set paste alot. I might be using it the wrong way.
Can anyone please give me a detailed explaination as to how i can use it?
I would be very grateful , Thankyou!

Comment: copy the file to clipboard, then insert it in a plain text editor like notepad++, then copy it again from there and then copy it to vim.. does it work?

Comment: Tried that too. Doesnt work .

Comment: The `:se paste` answer assumes vim, but the question and its tags just say "vi". All vi clones have the `autoindent` (`ai`) option, but only vim has `paste`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in `vi`, enter the escape mode using <kbd>Esc</kbd>.  Then say `:set paste`.

Now you should be able to paste text unmodified.

You can turn `'paste'` off by saying `:set nopaste`.

In order to make the change permanent, you can add `:set paste` to your `${HOME}/.vimrc`.

Comment: Just tried it exactly this way. Not working. The text is still indented unncessarily.

Comment: What about `:set noautoindent`?  Does that work?

Comment: Yes that works perfectly fine. Thank you so very much!Thats a big relief.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're either not copying the indentation of the first line or because you're pasting on an already indented position.

Comment: I didn't quite understand you.
I create a new file, lets say by

vi example

and paste my copied and indented code immediately after pressing 'I'.
It still creates all the unnecessary indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Its not exactly an answer but you can remove the extra tab in the beginning this way

```
:%s/^^I//g
```

where ^I is the tab character and you can type it by pressing C-v and then tab.

(or type the following sequence

```
gg    "goto top
c-v   "visual selection
S-G   "goto end of file
<<    " indent visual selection one to the left.
```

)